# Белые линии при запуске

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста, второй раз так диск умирает уже...

Перед выключением компа все закрыл и выключил через верхнюю панель (не по кнопке на ноуте), включаю сейчас и тупо чёрный экран, нажимаю на стрелку влево и alt появляется окно, но там ничего не понятно... я приложил фотку, помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Фотки не видно. Используйте кнопку править

Comment: @dlm0n добавил, размер большой слишком был...

Comment: А если с флешки загрузиться, работает? *"диск умирает"* Как определили, что это диск?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat с флешки загружается, но флешка установочная. Я не знаю, умирает или нет, ему неделя, ибо неделю назад была подобная проблема и диск пришлось выкинуть.... я не знаю, что это может быть... уже даже предположений нет. В прошлый раз пытался переустановить просто Linux, но не получалось выдавал там какую-то ошибку. В этот раз надо восстановить 100% ибо проект на реакте за целый день там лежит без копии на git

Comment: Если загружаться с флешки, должно быть видно содержимое диска, которое можно куда-то сохранить (флешка/инет). А потом можно попробовать переустановить убунту, и узнать какая конкретно ошибка.

Comment: Я не могу в диск зайти, ошибку выдаёт: error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd64: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or mount point busy

Comment: Получается переустановить Linux без ошибок.

Comment: Я закрывать не буду, ибо думаю повториться ещё подобное.... если кто-нибудь всё-таки знает решение, напишите пожалуйста, у меня так ещё второй диск валятся

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуй, попробуй устоновить Windows/Linux на флешку или на какойто диск и попробовать загрузится с флешки\диска и восстановить свои файлы, при этом делай это с низким разришением экрана так-как ты уже говорил что ты загружался с устоновочной флешки(обыно установшики бывают в низком разрешение экрана). Я предпологаю что это связано с видеокартой(у меня когда произошла проблема на карте что-то подобное было с твоей фотографией, при этом в низком разрешение все было нормально), к тому же ты уже говорил что это 2. диск(и это обозначает что проблема не в ОС).Надеюсь я хоть как-то помог.